# How to properly access a SQL database in Python based on Perl example?

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I'm trying to access this sql database based on the following lines of perl.

```perl
my $phyloDB = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:phylodb;host=mysql-lan-dev", "access", "access")
    or die "Unable to connect to database: $DBI::errstr";
my $db_taxstr = $phyloDB->prepare('SELECT a.taxonomy FROM contigs a, proteins b WHERE a.name = b.contig_name AND b.seguid = ? limit 1');
my $db_taxstr_sp = $phyloDB->prepare('SELECT taxonomy FROM contigs WHERE species = ? limit 1');
```

I'm not exactly sure where to begin because I don't know if this is calling a specific file or is grabbing this from a server.  I'm fairly new to sql databases and would rather load in a sql database and navigate the objects in Python than going down a wormhole of documentation.

I looked into https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html but I'm not sure where to begin.

**How can I load in this sql database in Python?**

Comment: Look into this [link](https://www.python-course.eu/sql_python.php)

Comment: This connects to the MySQL server on host `mysql-lan-dev`, and acceses the DB named `phylodb`.

Answer (score -1):

First install pymysql

```
pip install --user pymysql
```

Then run this in python.

```
import pymysql.cursors

# Connect to the database
connection = pymysql.connect(host='mysql-lan-dev',
                             user='access',
                             password='access',
                             db='phylodb',
                             charset='utf8mb4',
                             cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

try:

    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        # Read a single record
        sql = "SELECT a.taxonomy FROM contigs a, proteins b WHERE a.name = b.contig_name AND b.seguid = ? limit 1"
        cursor.execute(sql)
        result = cursor.fetchone()
        print(result)

        sql = "SELECT taxonomy FROM contigs WHERE species = ? limit 1"
        cursor.execute(sql)
        result = cursor.fetchone()
        print(result)

finally:
    connection.close()
```

Comment: You're missing the parameters that go with the placeholdres. Also, pymysql uses `%s` for placeholders, not `?`.

Answer (score -2):

Use sqlalchemy module for Python. It has very good documentation.
You can use it by "hands" and as ORM.

```
pip install sqlalchemy ( or pip3 install sqlalchemy )
```

Then import this module in your project file.

```
>>> from sqlalchemy import create_engine
>>> engine = create_engine('mysql://user:pass@host/db')
>>> engine.execute("select 'Hello, World!'").scalar()
>>> u'Hello, World!'
```

Or:

```
>>> from sqlalchemy import Table, MetaData
>> meta = MetaData(bind=e, reflect=True)
>>> table = meta.tables['table']
>>> list(e.execute(table.select(table.c.id < 2)))
>>>    [(1, u'first row')]
```

Or:

```
>>> from sqlalchemy import orm
>>> class Table(object):
>>>...     pass
>>> orm.Mapper(Table, meta.tables['table'])
>>> s = orm.Session(bind=e)
>>> s.query(Table).filter(Table.id < 2).first().info
>>>    u'first row'
```

Comment: Use code formatting, not quote formatting, for code.